# Adjucate a Timeless modifier for a "Item Box" or "Inventory" power

Tags: powers, gurps-4e

I am trying to run an Isekai campaign, and I want an advantage that works like the "item box" or "inventory" that is so popular in those stories.

Browsing the "powers" rulebook, I've found under Snatcher:

> For storage only, buy **Payload** with the **Cosmic** modifier.

The payload advantage gives you 10%/lv of your light load as storage for 1pt/lv, the cosmic modifier allows it to go into a subspace for +50%;

So the advantage looks like this:

> **Item Box** 1.5pt / level (Payload 1/lv + Cosmic +50%)
>
> Allows one to store items weighing up to 10% of the character's Light Load per level of the advantage, in a subspace. Items can only be stored or retrieved by the character.

Now I would like to slap a modifier on that advantage so time does not pass for items inside the storage. How much **%** should be this *timeless* modifier?

---

By the comments, the setting is a high fantasy medieval swords & spell. TL is middle ages. Available spells for starting players are only those in the 4th ed Basic Set.

Comment: I think the answer will vary depending on how important the modifier *Timeless* is the campaign. That is, in the setting you're imagining do magical materials decay so quickly that being able to have them always fresh makes the PC omnipotent? Or is the setting such that this is just a quirk that allows a PC to always have a ripe banana?

Comment: @heyicanchan I don't think it makes that much of a difference, but more data on the premises is always good. I added relevant objective info to the Q body.

Comment: Looked up the Payload advantage. I think you may want to rearrange your question. That is, first detail the homebrew timeless modifier to the Payload advantage *then* provide context *then* ask for an estimate of the modifier's value. (Also, steel yourself: I have *a lot* of questions about the power generally, like *Must things I store appear in my hands?* (i.e. Can the space be used to dump acid on foes?) and *Can I store energy?* (i.e. Can ambient light be tucked into the space so as to create darkness now and bursts of light later?) and stuff like that!)

Answer (score 1):

- For timeless storage for material objects, I think it's another instance of Cosmic, at +100%, in addition to the existing +50%, for +150%.
- For timeless storage that you can store light in, or an explosion that's beginning to go off, or similar things, it would be Cosmic, at +300%, for a total of +350%. This would include handling material objects.

Source: ***Power-Ups 4: Enhancements***, pp. 6-8. +100% is the "Cheating" level of Cosmic, and +300% is the "Godlike Tricks" level.

For both of these, I'd require some minimum amount of Payload to be purchased, so that the timelessness actually took a noticeable bite out of the character's point budget. Just buying Payload 1 at +350%, for 5 points, is *too cheap* for, say, a 250 point character.

Comment: That 100% in the first line,  it is two cosmic for +50% (subdimensional storage) and +50% (timeless storage)???

Comment: Even in your extreme case, it is 0.1 of your light noad for every 5 points. It is very little load. Though I don't think it is godlike. Cheating, yes.

Comment: Putting light in a box and stopping it is godlike AFAICS. Clarified the modifiers.

Comment: the payload advantage in basic already states what can and can not be put in.

Comment: @Mindwin: Using enough Cosmic will lift such limitations.

Comment: maybe an "affect insubstantial" for +100% is more adequate